# Regex Express Return All Chars before a '/' but if there are 2 '/' Return all before that

Tags: regex

I have been trying to get a regex expression to return me the following in the following situations.

```
XX         ->   XX
XXX        ->   XXX
XX/XX      ->   XX
XX/XX/XX   ->   XX/XX
XXX/XXX/XX ->   XXX/XXX
```

I had the following Regex, however they do no work.

```
^[^/]+     => https://regex101.com/r/xvCbNB/1
=========
([A-Z])\w+ => https://regex101.com/r/xvCbNB/2
```

They are close but are not there.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get all text from the start till the last occurrence of a specific character or till the end of string if the character is missing.

Use

```
^(?:.*(?=\/)|.+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xafWqF/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A.*(%3F%3D%2F)%7C.%2B)):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:.*(?=\/)|.+)` - a non-capturing group that matches either of the two alternatives, and if the first one matches first the second won't be tried:

  - `.*(?=\/)` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible upt to but excluding `/`
  - `|` - or
  - `.+` - any 1+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

Answer (score 3):

It will be easier to use a replace here to match `/` followed by non-slash characters before end of line:

Search regex:

```
/[^/]*$
```

Replacement String:

```
""
```

[Updated RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/xvCbNB/3)

---

If you're looking for a regex match then use this regex:

```
^(.*?)(?:/[^/]*)?$
```

[Updated RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/xvCbNB/4)

Answer (score 1):

Any special reason it has to be a regular expression? How about just splitting the string at the slashes, remove the last item and rejoin:

```
function removeItemAfterLastSlash(string) {
  const list = string.split(/\//);
  if (list.length == 1) [
     return string;
  } 

  list.pop();
  return list.join("/");
}
```

Or look for the last slash an remove it:

```
function removeItemAfterLastSlash(string) {
  const index = string.lastIndexOf("/");
  if (index === -1) {
    return string;
  }
  return string.splice(0, index);
}
```

Comment: this was for an Oracle SQL Query so JavaScript was no good here, but good solution for JavaScript!